# JAVA - ERROR CLEAN INSTALL IL_INFINITE_RECURSIVE_LOOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-storage

Porque da error IL_INFINITE_RECURSIVE_LOOP al hacer clean and install ?

interface devuelve un resource al leer blob storage de azure:

```
default Resource readFileFromBlob(String filename, String containerName){
   return readFileFromBlob(filename, containerName);
}
```

Implement:

```
@Override
public Resource readFileFromBlob(String filename, String containerName) {
    log.info("connection:{}", properties.getConfiguration().getStorageConnectionStr());
    BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(properties.getConfiguration().getStorageConnectionStr())
            .buildClient();

    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = 
    storageClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(filename);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    blobClient.download(outputStream);
    final byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return new ByteArrayResource(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es porque un método se llama a si mismo de forma infinita, revisando el código el error esta la implementación del default de la interfaz:

```
  default Resource readFileFromBlob(String filename, String containerName){
     return readFileFromBlob(filename, containerName);
  }
```

Lo que sucede es que el método `readFileFromBlob` hace `return readFileFromBlob(filename, containerName);` entonces el método hace un return de si mismo lo que causa un bucle infinito, para solucionarlo retorna el método correcto que contenga la lógica implementada o quita la implementación default.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta Roberto, si tuve que cambiar el método con eso solucione el error 
ByteArrayResource readtofile(String filename, String containerName);